# Path to VBS scheduled script not found

Tags: vbscript

I have a task created in Windows Task Scheduler which runs a `vbs script`. I am getting the following error:

[image: Path to the script not found]

It looks like the Task stops looking for the script to run when it finds a space in the path.

However, the path is quoted in the task:

[image: Script path]

The workaround is to put underscore instead of each space but that would require further workarounds and is not the best way to do it.

How can I set up the task successfully?

Comment: Don't use mapped drives. Use UNC paths. `\\server\sharename\folder\file.ext`. Drives are mapped by user token. Admins have two. Limited and Admin. Drives mapped to one are not available in the other. If not using your account then no other account has access to your mapped drives. Mapped drives have been obsolete for more than 20 years. But they refuse to die.

Comment: The script is stored on a local drive (P:). Even if I move the script to the desktop, I get the same error.

Comment: Who do you get an error message from excel? I don't see how Excel could be involved here. All you mentioned was task scheduler and vbs script.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please, if you have the chance spend a little time reading [ask] then [edit] the question to provide a [mcve]. At the moment we cannot even see what the full `Program/script` command you are trying to set is as it's cropped off in the image.